# How to covert a mySql DB into Drupal format tables

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal

Hi there i have some sql tables and i want to convert these in a "Drupal Node Format" but i don't know how to do it. Does someone knows at least which tables i have to write in order to have a full node with all the keys etc. ?

I will give an example :

I have theses Objects :

**Anime**
field animeID
field animeName

**Producer**
field producerID
field producerName

**AnimeProducers**
field animeID
field producerID

I have used the CCK module and i had created in my drupal a new Content Type Anime and a new Data Type Producer that exist in an Anime object.

How can i insert all the data from my simple mysql db into drupal ?

Sorry for the long post , i would like to give you the chance to understand my problem

Thx in advance for your time to read my post

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the Feeds module to import flat CSV files, or there is a module called Migrate that seems promising (albiet pretty intense). Both work on Drupal 6 or 7.

Answer (score 0):

mmmmm.... i think you can export CVS from your sql database and then use

http://drupal.org/project/node_import

to import this cvs data to nodes.....mmmm i don know if there is another non-programmatically way

Comment: unfortunately i am using drupal 7 so this module is not supported by this version :( thx for the reply thow

Answer (score 0):

The main tables for node property data are `node` and `node_revision`, have a look at the columns in those and it should be fairly obvious what needs to go in those.

As far as fields go, their storage is predictable so you would be able automate an import (although I don't envy you having to write that!). If your field is called 'field_anime' it's data will live in two tables: `field_data_field_anime` and `field_revision_field_anime` which are keyed by the entity ID (in this case node ID), entity type (in the case 'node' itself) and bundle (in this case the name of your node type). You should keep both tables up to date to ensure the revision system functions correctly.

The simplest way to do it though is with PHP and the node API functions:

```
/* This is for a single node, obviously you'd want to loop through your custom SQL data here */
$node = new stdClass;
$node->type = 'my_type';
$node->title = 'Title';
node_object_prepare($node);

// Fields
$node->field_anime[LANGUAGE_NONE] = array(0 => array('value' => $value_for_field));
$node->field_producer[LANGUAGE_NONE] = array(0 => array('value' => $value_for_field));
// And so on...

// Finally save the node
node_save($node);
```

If you use this method Drupal will handle a lot of the messy stuff for you (for example updating the `taxonomy_index` table automatically when adding a taxonomy term field to a node)